# Apache 403 everywhere with XAMPP Linux

Tags: linux, apache, xampp

I'm fairly new to using Apache, we use XAMPP here so I need to use that for simplicities sake. I'm having a problem getting Apache to view my files. I get this error in the logs for httpd:

```
[Thu Sep 17 16:16:46.944172 2020] [core:error] [pid 10036] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:39318] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/mrblob/Documents') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Thu Sep 17 16:16:47.170688 2020] [core:error] [pid 10036] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:39318] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/mrblob/Documents') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://localhost:81/
```

My files for my website is /home/mrblob/Documents/web/

I've got this in my httpd.cnf file:

```
<Directory "/home/mrblob/Documents/web/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Require all granted
    Order allow,deny
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've also tried chmod on different permissions... I've tried a lot of different things... I'm yet to get it to work. FYI phpmyadmin as well as XAMPP's dashboard works fine. Any other pages that I want throws 403.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm also fairly new to Linux's permission system.

Answer (score 0):

So I worked out I just needed to give access to Apache, well, I knew I needed to do this but I tried everything I thought of. My

> sudo chmod ugo+rwx

Which I know its not the most secure way of doing it, but I'm only local hosting for now so it's not a huge deal.